# Can't find anomalies / abnormalities in wireshark capture

Tags: attacks, wireshark, tcp

[image]

Previous post was deleted for not enough context, which I apologise for. I will try to provide as much context as I can. I am aware this appears to be an example of a SYN flood attack with spoofed ip addresses, however should there not be a SYN ACK response from the server?

I was wondering if anyone was able to find any abnormalities or such in this capture that could explain this behaviour.

From what I found, in frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10 and 18 there is a "Source MAC must not be a group address" warning
Frame 1's MAC address as an example, is 49:4a:12:0e:64:f5

There is also another warning, "The acknowledgment number field is nonzero while the ACK flag is not set". Frame 1's acknowledgment number is 1957080919.

[Here's the capture file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wk6OzEEwSfndBzHtjLVpWh_EcTwUQC9f/view?usp=sharing)

It should provide more context than I can

Comment: Screenshot doesn't match pcap file; one is TCP the other is ICMP.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, the packets are being sent to TCP port 0.  To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)),

> For TCP, port number 0 is reserved and cannot be used

So either the operating system or the firewall (if any) are silently dropping the packets.  Responding with a SYN/ACK would be inappropriate as the server cannot accept traffic on TCP port 0.